Evaluation of the given line integral
Question: Evaluate $\int_{C}$B.dr along the curve $x^{2}$+$y^{2}$=1,$z$= 1 in the positive direction from (0,1,2) to (1,0,2);given
B= (xz²+y)i+(z-y)j+(xy-z)k
The question itself is easy,but I don't know how to handle z=1
Here's my attempt:-
$\int_{C}$B.dr= $\int_{C}$(xz²+y)i+(z-y)j+(xy-z)k.(dxi+dyj+dzk)
=$\int_{C}$(xz²+y)dx+$\int_{C}$(z-y)dy+$\int_{C}$(xy-z)dz
Should I put z=1 in the above integral?after this I will integrate all the three integrals and put up the values given in the question.

You should use the parametrisation $x=sin(t),y=cos(t),z=2, 0\leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$  ( I have written "$z=2$" as your coordinates suggest that we are on the curve $x^2+y^2=1, z=2$, but it contradicts your curve written in the question, so you may want to check you have written the question correctly).

The question is correct.

The question as it stands cannot be correct as (0,1,2) and (1,0,2) do not lie on the curve.

As J.D pointed out, yes, it looks like the coordinates tell $z = 2$ while your question says $z = 1$. So there might be something to check in your notes.
In either case, this does not matter much since $z = \text{cst}$. So the answer to your question is: yes. You can replace $z$ by its constant value in your above integrals (and you will have $\mathrm{d}z = 0$, so that the third integral vanishes, since $z \equiv$ constant).
The reason for that is that your curve is defined on a slice of constant height ($z = 1$ or $z = 2$, depending on what your question says). So in a way, your curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1, z = 1$ is simply a curve in the plane $\{z = 1\}$. And as such, you can forget about the third dimension, and do everything like it were on the plane. (By setting $z = 1$ wherever $z$ appears, and $\mathrm{d}z = 0$).

Made my life easier, thanks

It's a question from Calcutta honours examination (1985)
